# How to get intermediate dates in MySql query

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have two tables: default_menu and promote_menu, the first one contains two fields:

```
id  item
10  mozarella
35  cheddar
```

the second one contains three fields:

```
id  item  date
10  feta  2015-01-01
10  feta  2015-01-05
10  feta  2015-01-20
```

I wanna build an sql query by which I can the following type of info using date range(like 2015-01-01 till 2015-01-05) and id(like id=10):

```
date        item      type
2015-01-01  feta      promo
2015-01-02  mozarella default
2015-01-03  mozarella default
2015-01-04  mozarella default
2015-01-05  feta      promo
```

How can I do this with one mysql query?

Comment: You should make the list of dates by a  procedure or an additional table and then use left join to take the result

Comment: Here's a writeup. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried to do this with one select query but I think it is impossible. Can you show me an example how can I make the list or an additional table ?

Comment: does item in default_menu is related with item in promote_menu?